# pine script : how to add and display text on a horizontal line / hline?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I want to include a text input feature to add text onto horizontal lines / Hlines that I am plotting onto a rate-of-change indicar. These lines are essentially like 70/30 RSI overbought and oversold lines, but I am using them instead for probability zones. I want to be able to write in text that will show up on each line in the plot.  Tradingview provides a custom horizontal line drawing tool with a text input and option to align the text to right, center or left. I would like these features included inside a rate of change indicator with the set of horizontal lines which mark of the probability zones.
Thank you for any help

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Rate Of Change", shorttitle="ROC-w-prb-lne", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
length = input.int(1, minval=1)
source = input(close, "Source")
roc = 100 * (source - source[length])/source[length]
plot(roc, color=#2962FF, title="ROC-w-probty ln")
hline(0.5, color=#edde35, title="50% (+25%) prob Line")
hline(-0.5, color=#edde35, title="50% (-25%) prob line")
hline(1.0, color=#2950de, title="75% (+38%) Line")
hline(-1.0, color=#2950de, title="75% (-36%) Line")
hline(2.5, color=#787B86, title="95% (+48%) line")
hline(-2.5, color=#787B86, title="95% (-48%) line")
hline(3.5, color=#c73030, title="98% (+49%) line")
hline(-3.5, color=#c73030, title="98% (-49%) line")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a 'label' if you want to display some text. Set its `y` argument to your `hline`'s value, and manipulate the `x` argument as you wish.

You can use `bar_index`, `chart.left_visible_bar_time` or `chart.right_visible_bar_time` to manipulate the `x` coordinate.

Below are some examples:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

hline_price_1 = 100
hline_price_2 = 75
hline_price_3 = 50
hline_price_4 = 25

hline(hline_price_1)
hline(hline_price_2)
hline(hline_price_3)
hline(hline_price_4)

label hline_label_1 = label.new(bar_index, hline_price_1, str.tostring(hline_price_1), style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.white)
label hline_label_2 = label.new(bar_index - 50, hline_price_2, str.tostring(hline_price_2), style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.white)
label hline_label_3 = label.new(chart.left_visible_bar_time, hline_price_3, str.tostring(hline_price_3), xloc=xloc.bar_time, style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.white)
label hline_label_4 = label.new(chart.right_visible_bar_time, hline_price_4, str.tostring(hline_price_4), xloc=xloc.bar_time, style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.white)

label.delete(hline_label_1[1])
label.delete(hline_label_2[1])
label.delete(hline_label_3[1])
label.delete(hline_label_4[1])
```

[image]

Comment: I have been a developer for almost 30 years.  Very new to pine script.  Knew there had to be a way to accomplish this.  This is perfect.